# How to string compare const uint8* in a ESP32 microcontroller chip

Tags: microcontroller, c, esp32

I'm sending data from an ionic app (typescript) to an ESP32chip.  Data from the app uses protocol buffer format.  Here's the code:

```
this.provisionMgrAction.setAction('stop');
let bytesOfStuff = await this.provisionMgrAction.serializeBinary();
BleClient.write(this.deviceID, serviceID, characteristicID, bytesOfStuff);
```

On the ESP chip side (code in C), data is received as "stop".  The log (ESP_LOGI line below) prints value of inbuf as "stop"  (without quotation marks).

```
esp_err_t custom_prov_data_handler(uint32_t session_id, const uint8_t *inbuf, ssize_t inlen,
                                          uint8_t **outbuf, ssize_t *outlen, void *priv_data)
{
    if (inbuf) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Received data: %.*s", inlen, (char *)inbuf);
        if (strcmp(inbuf, "stop") == 0) {
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "print something");
        }
    }
}
```

But strcmp doesn't seem to work.  I'm presuming it has something to do with the fact that when "stop" is sent over BLE from the client side app to the ESP32 chip, it comes without a null character, though I'm not sure how to confirm that.  In any event, how do I make sure that strcmp equates the value of inbuf to "stop"?  Do I need to add a null character to inbuf?  If yes, how do I accomplish that?  Or do I need to compare inbuf to "stop\0"?  The length of inbuf (inlen) is printed out to be 2 more than the number of characters in the message that is transmitted to the chip over BLE (in this case, 6).

Comment: Yes, if you get 6 bytes in and there is no null character received after the letters "stop", it means that the incoming string is longer than the four character null terminated string of "stop", so it means that the strings will never be equal and won't match. But this really has nothing to do with electronics, microcontrollers or ESP32, that's just a generic C programming problem and any C resource should explain which comparison methods are available in C and how they work.

Comment: What characters do you receive actually? Don't just print them as string (`"%s"`) but as hex to reveal null and/or control characters.

Comment: @the busybee How exactly do you print const uint8_t * (const unsigned char *) in hex?  Tried %x formatter, but that doesn't match the argument type const uint8_t *.

Comment: To print this array, the easy way is to do what you did (your comment in the answer below) -- just hand-code a solution that works only for a six-byte receive string. Otherwise, there is a good, general solution but it's a bit of a hassle to implement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357031/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-in-c

Comment: If you use protocol buffers to encode, use them to decode…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the problem is the `'\0'` character that is missing.

You could use [strncmp](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncmp.htm) and specify the length (here it would be `inlen -2`  I guess, the 2 more might be checksum or something like that)

Like

```
if (strncmp(inbuf, "stop", inlen - 2) == 0)
```

That should work.

Also, be cautious if you sometime answer from ESP32. Depending on the app side you would also need a termination character (for example on Android Studio Java I needed to add `'\n'` because I called `ReadLine` function).

So based on the values extracted in hexa from the buffer you can get your info using

```
if (strncmp((char *)&inbuf[2], "stop", inlen - 2) == 0)
```

Comment: When using strncmp, your solution gives the following error: `note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'const uint8_t *' {aka 'const unsigned char *'}`  But changing it to `if (strncmp((char *)inbuf, "stop", inlen -2 ) == 0)` seems to resolve that error.  That said, the comparison still doesn't pan out.  What am I missing?

Comment: Ok you could try to print char by char instead of %.*s the hexa value
Something like inbuf[0], inbuf[1] ... inbuf[5] inbuf[6] so you know exactly what is in your buffer

Comment: So my hex printout (`ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Received data: %x, %x, %x, %x, %x, %x, %x",  inbuf[0], inbuf[1], inbuf[2], inbuf[3], inbuf[4], inbuf[5], inbuf[6]);` gives the following: a, 4, 73, 74, 6f, 70, 0.  Not sure what the a, 4 stand for (could this be because I'm using protocol buffer to send data over BLE?), but characters 73, 74, 6f and 70 translate to "stop".

Comment: Ok that's nice, they may be BLE info and some CRC you may want to look at the BLE communication if really want to understand it.
Well the good news is that you now can compare but not starting from the pointer you should start 2 characters after

Comment: Something like if (strncmp(&inbuf[2], "stop", inlen - 2) == 0) should work now

Comment: @coder101 an educated guess would be that you're looking at a weird string format that is BOTH a Pascal-style string and a C-style string. Pascal encodes strings as [(length) + (bytes)], so "stop" would be 0x04 0x73 0x74 0x6F 0x70. The C language encodes strings as [(bytes) + \0], so "stop" would be 0x73 0x74 0x6F 0x70 0x00. Here you have 0x04 0x73 0x74 0x6F 0x70 0x00, which is both of those put together. Of course, an easy way to prove / disprove this is to send a longer string to your app!

Comment: no the trame is 0x0A 0x04 0x73 0x74 0x6F 0x70 0x00 but you are right 
0x0A may be some start of transmission character from the BLE i guess

Comment: Regardless of string length, inbuf always begins with 0x0A, followed by the length of the string (excluding null character), followed by the actual string transmitted.  Turns out that the transmitted string has a null character in the end.  So the issue wasn't so much the null character itself; it was the first two characters (0x0A, 0xstring_length) which caused strcmp to fail.  The following solution does the trick: `if (strcmp((char *)&inbuf[2], "stop") == 0)`

Comment: Good for you, from a developer point of view I would use strncmp as you give the total lenght it would be more robust in case someday changing the module or whatever the null character disapear and you end up having to debug the whole thing again

Comment: 0x0A is the '\n' character by the way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Count the amount of received characters in the *payload*. If they aren't 4, you can stop there because the input is obviously wrong.
2. If there is no null termination, you don't have a C string but just a raw data array. If you don't *need* this to become a C string, then the fastest and easiest is `memcmp(inbuf, "stop", 4);`. This doesn't rely on null termination.
3. In case you need to re-use the data later as a C string, then just do `inbuf[4] = '\0'` to append a null terminator manually to the 5th character. Now you could use `strcmp` but there's no real point of using it over `memcmp` when you already know the data size. `memcmp` is always faster than `strcmp`.

I can't think of any scenario where it would make sense for you to use `strncmp`.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback re memcmp.  But there's nothing wrong with the input.  The app uses protocol buffer to pack the data, which in the process of serializing the input string to binary, inserts '\n' along with the length of the input string at the beginning of the data being transmitted.  Hence the two additional pieces of data at the beginning of inbuf in my code above.

Comment: @coder101 When coding any form of data communication, you always need lots of error checks. You can never assume "this protocol will never be wrong".

Comment: I get it now what you were trying to say in your answer - more about error checks than the input actually being incorrect.  Thanks.